# What was this novel about God's librarian apprentices?

Tags: story-identification, novel

This is a novel I read a couple years ago (so at least that old), but I'm fairly sure it came out after 2010.

It centers around a bunch of people who are apprentices of someone who is not called God but might as well be God. The apprentices live in a library; the library is protected by zombies and dogs. Each apprentice studies a different topic and is not allowed to learn about other apprentices' topics; some of the topics include math, violence, animals, healing, and the afterlife. The apprentices dress oddly because they grew up in the library and don't understand fashion.

An initial plot point involves God going missing. Later the Sun goes out and is then replaced with a black sun. The main/POV characters are the apprentice who focuses on human languages, a burglar, and a US government agent of some sort (military? FBI?). One of the chapters is titled "Half a Fuckton of Lying-Ass Lies".

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is *[The Library at Mount Char](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Library_at_Mount_Char)* by Scott Hawkins.

> Carolyn had lived with eleven "siblings" under the care of a
> millennia-old and godlike man known to them as Father (also known as
> Ablakha or Adam Black), prone to acts of sadistic cruelty. All have
> strange powers, learned from books held in Father's library. Carolyn
> employs Steve Hodgson, a goodhearted former minor league housebreaker
> to break into a house for her. Unknown to him, she wanted to conceal
> evidence of a murder committed by her. Hodgson dies, betrayed by
> Carolyn.

Chapter 6 is titled

> "*About Half a Fuckton of Lying-Ass Lies*"

Comment: Just read the wiki summary, that's the one. Thanks!