# Novel about a crazy god who abducts children and teaches them skills

Tags: story-identification, novel

Looking for a novel, probably in the fantasy genre.

From the point of view of a girl, who was abducted by some crazy and cruel supreme being, whom she calls 'father'.

She, along with other kids, was raised by this god. Every kid was taught a different skillset. They lived in a village which had zombies for residents. She was some kind of librarian.

Among the other kids there was:

- a necromancer girl who could walk the afterlife, 'father' killed her a few times, then resurrected her.
- a guy who could talk to animals, but lost the ability to communicate with humans,
- some other guy who was a warrior? and who was punished by 'father' for some minor disobedience by burning him alive in a sarcophagus.

It seemed as if all the kids raised by father were suffering from CPSTD, but they could do nothing to resist him and his 'education'.

There was some kind of taking leopard-god, whom the girl tricks into walking into a trap to get rid of him.

At the beginning of the story, 'father' disappears, and the kids - now adults - assemble to find out what happened to father and discuss the succession.

These 'siblings' (the successors of 'father') are all supernatural beings with long lifespan, possibly immortals, due to his lessons.

The siblings all lived in different parts of the world and returned after hearing of father's disappearance.

There's an enemy they should defeat who is more cruel than 'father'.

No idea about the cover; I read it anywhere between 3-10 years ago. I did not finish it, so this is all I remember.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year or decade did you read this, and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall any details about the cover?

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/258399/what-was-this-novel-about-gods-librarian-apprentices

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The Library at Mount Char](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/26892110-the-library-at-mount-char) by Scott Hawkins.

[image: The Library at Mount Char]

Previously asked about in [What was this novel about God's librarian apprentices?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/258399/what-was-this-novel-about-gods-librarian-apprentices). As far as I know this is Hawkins only book, which is a shame because I think it's a terrific book and indeed one of the best fantasy books I've read. [There is a Wikipedia article about it here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Library_at_Mount_Char), but don't read it if you haven't finished the book as it contains spoilers.

The protagonist is *Carolyn*. The book starts with here walking home covered in blood having just arranged a bloody murder as the start of her plans. However I can't say any more about what those plans are as it will spoil the book for you.

> Carolyn, blood-drenched and barefoot, walked alone down the two-lane stretch of blacktop that the Americans called Highway 78. Most of the librarians, Carolyn included, had come to think of this road as the Path of Tacos, so-called in honor of a Mexican joint they snuck out to sometimes. The guacamole, she remembered, is really good. Her stomach rumbled. Oak leaves, reddish-orange and delightfully crunchy, crackled underfoot as she walked. Her breath puffed white in the predawn air. The obsidian knife she had used to murder Detective Miner lay nestled in the small of her back, sharp and secret.
>
> She was smiling

The girl who can raise the dead is *Jennifer* and the boy who can talk to animals is *Michael*. The warrior is *David*, who has been trained to be a ruthless killer. He is punished by Father by being burned alive in a hollow bronze bull that *Father* uses as a barbeque.

I don't recall an enemy that they need to defeat, but there are hints of other supernatural beings who will contest the rulership of the world now that *Father* is dead. We never find out much about them.

Comment: that's the one, thank you.

Comment: @hey It's a fantastic book and well worth finishing if you can find a copy.